# Problem with snap layer when in name is space

Tags: openlayers-2, layers, snapping

I'm trying to make a option where user can choose layer to snap. All is okay when layers names are without space, but if there is a space in the name (like 'something layer name') snapping does not work.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an "underscore" between each word in the name. So instead of Layer Name, you would use Layer_Name.
You can rename the layers in the properties and it should work for your purposes.

Comment: Yes, but I can't rename layers because these layers names are stored in database and I load data from database and I can't rename data in database because this data are used in other functions, methods, etc.